# Docker Redis existed after started

Tags: docker, redis

I follow the guideline in this link https://hub.docker.com/_/redis, I start a redis instance as follows

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

But the container is stop immediately after starting. Could you help me on this?

Comment: What's the output of `docker logs some-redis`?

Comment: Fatal error, can't open config file '-p'

Comment: I had no problem running docker with the command, I hope some-redis is not stopped, instead it is daemonized as you used `-d`. Can you re-check it's status with `docker ps`?

Comment: same here, no problem with mine. may you are building your own redis image?

Comment: run with `docker run --name some-redis -it redis`

Comment: it's not be listed in docker ps, I don't build my own :(

Comment: This is strange as how `-p` was be print here. Could you run `docker rm -f some-redis` first then `docker run --name some-redis -d redis` again?

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/120 for `Fatal error, can't open config file '-p' –`

Comment: I make it work by run as Adiii suggest docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -it redis

Comment: Interesting, maybe @Adiii could explain how it could work...

Comment: Ah perfect. but this will in the foreground do not forget this :) let run with to allocate pseudo tty `docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -dit redis`

Comment: I think the option order maybe a root cause, if I add -p or -d after -it redis, it will fail, but if I move  before redis image name, it's fine

Comment: Yeah, I just add -d for background. By the way, how can I highlight text in comment as you do? light gray background I mean

Comment: are you able to run in the background now? you can backtick "`" to highlight code https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm

Comment: I can run it in thr background now. Thank @Adiii